# Rails: Create column that could be reference or could be string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a calls table with columns `Caller` and `Destination` which can be either reference (to `Employees` or `Candidates` table) or can be simple phone numbers, if I don't have employee or candidate with this number. Is it possible to manage this ambiguous behaviour in RoR?

Comment: Rails doesn't support ambiguity. It does lot of meta programming magic to handle `polymorphic`  relation where such ambiguity is out of scope.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought. I will create a separate table where I will handle all candidates/employees phone numbers matching and reference that in calls.

Comment: You can also create two columns and have a getter that evaluates what to return based on your own logic.